# A question about the proof of the limit comparison test for series

Tags: calculus

A question about the proof of the limit comparison test for series:

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Limit_comparison_test

About the the last part: $b_n(c-\epsilon)<a_n<(c+\epsilon)b_n$, to complete the proof, they then take just the RHS $a_n<(c+\epsilon)b_n$ and state that if $a_n$ diverges so does $b_n$ and if $b_n$ converges so does $a_n$. This is pretty straight forward, my question is, does it matter if I'll use the RHS or the LHS in this proof, i.e $b_n(c-\epsilon)<a_n$  ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$a_n < (c+\epsilon)b_n$ means that by direct comparison, you know that if $b_n$ converges, then $a_n$ converges.

$(c-\epsilon)b_n<a_n$ can be rewritten as $b_n<\frac{a_n}{c-\epsilon}$ and means that if $a_n$ converges, then $b_n$ converges.

Both sides of the inequality are used, not only one.

Comment: Why then it isn't enough to use just one side ?

Comment: @GinKin Because one side gives you the statement "if $a_n$ converges, then $b_n$" converges, and the other gives you the statement "if $b_n$ converges, then $a_n$ converges." You cannot claim that if $a_n$ converges and $a_n < (c+\epsilon) b_n$, then $b_n$ converges. Taking $b_n=1$ for all $b$ will show that.

Comment: Yes, but in this case $a_n < (c+\epsilon) b_n$ if $b_n$ converges then $a_n$ converges, and if $a_n$ diverges so does $b_n$. So what's wrong with using just one side like this ?

Comment: True. But you want to prove that if $a_n$ *converges*, then $b_n$ converges. You cannot prove that fro the fact that $a_n<(c+\epsilon)b_n$ alone.

Comment: @GinKin I mean, there is nothing wrong with using only one side to prove that if $b_n$ converges, then $a_n$ converges. It proves this point just fine. But to prove the whole theorem, you must also prove that if $a_n$ converges, then $b_n$ converges, and for this, you need the other inequality.